# Why can't we serialize a concrete class which derives from an interface?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I don't understand why we can't serialize a concrete class that derives from an interface. The properties of the concrete class are still known!

```
public interface IThing
{
    string Name { get; }
}

[XmlRoot]
public class RealThing : IThing
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get { return "Real Thing"; } set{ /* Do something. */ } }
}
```

I've told the `XmlSerializer` what to do with the implemented property, why would this not work? Why would the `XmlSerializer` even look at the interface?

I've made a ton of serializable classes and am just running into this now. Is it possible that none of the hundreds of serializable classes I've made in the past implemented an interface?

Comment: The only error I get with that class is that it is not public. Is there any specific error you are getting?

Comment: What is the error anyway? I just ran this code and works as expected. (the Name property won't get serialized, because it has no setter)

Comment: It looks like I've neglected to include the most important detail in my question - which is that the RealThing is actually List<IThing>, IThing - that is the problem and it's obvious now. Please disregard!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You certainly can serialize a class that inherits an interface. But you cannot tell the serializer to *serialize the interface*, because it wouldn't know which concrete class to instantiate on deserialization.

In other words serialization will work, if you instantiate your serializer like this:

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RealThing));
ser.Serialize(new MemoryStream(), new RealThing());
```

Also, you will need to make `RealThing` a public class, since that is required by `Xmlserializer`.

Comment: Yeah I mis-typed my example. But also this is no longer an issue - see my main comment for why (I overlooked the important part). Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your property needs a setter. The XML Serializer only serializes public, read/write properties.

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake in my example and is not causing the underlying issue. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I've just serialized RealThing ok with XmlSerializer.

Whatever your problem is, I don't think it's because RealThing implements an interface...